# Engine coolant not hot

Tags: coolant, cooling-system

Recently bought a 85 bronco ll with a 2.8 motor. Engine coolant won't reach normal temp. Changed the thermostat, flushed and refilled coolant, but still had the same problem. Replaced radiator cap, let engine warm up and temp rose to normal. Tried it the next day and had the same issue again. Also, when the blower is turned on it will blow hard and hot for a short time then slow down and blow cool.